# All database containers fail in a Kubernetes namespace - Init:Error

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I have a Kubernetes namespace that contains dozens of pods. All applications run smoothly, except all database pods. All database pods show `Init:Error`. This is something my colleagues and I have been observing for a while.

Example of how a single pod looks like (and there are many and all of them like that, only databases):

```sh
NAMESPACE       NAME                                                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AG
namespace       component-dbinit-job-9tbh6                                0/1     Init:Error         0          2d13h
```

There's no error messages and error logs.

Any idea where to look for an issue further? Have been stuck for a while.

Comment: have you tried describe? Or checked in the web interface of your kubernetes provider for more info? `kubectl describe pod -n [namespace] [pod_name]`

Comment: @RobEvans Yes, but there's no information whatsoever about any error - no errors. Just status `Failed`

Comment: share the output from kubectl describe pod <pod-name> command

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-init-containers/

Comment: whats the database image name

Comment: Obviously the problem is with init container, but I am unable to help you not knowing what this init container is doing. Provide complete yamls and init container sources.